# Offline database can't be restored: Exclusive access could not be obtained

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint

I'm practicing a SharePoint 2010 to 2013 migration and having trouble restoring a database. After backing up a database on a SP2010/SQL 2008 server, I'm trying to restore it to a database I've freshly created on my SP2013/SQL 2012 server.

Though the UI, I've taken the destination database offline. I select the `.bak` file, select my destination database, and attempt the restoration. I get an error: `Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.`

Why is this happening? I've taken the database offline, I don't see how it could possibly be in use.

In the restoration window, I've tried going to Options and selecting `Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)` as well as `Close existing connections to destination database`.

Still the same error message. How do I get past this error?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. Try the DBA site.

Comment: @MarcB I suppose that's true, though I imagine solutions for this might include some sort of SQL script.

Comment: Dont take the database offline. Just restore over it. Just kill all connections to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I had the same issue last week!

```
ALTER DATABASE [Test4] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

RESTORE DATABASE [Test4]
FROM DISK = 'c:\test4.BAK'
WITH MOVE 'Test4_Data' TO 'c:\data\Test4.mdf',
MOVE 'Test4_Log' TO 'c:\data\Test4_log.ldf'
```

detailed explanation can be found at http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1407/getting-exclusive-access-to-restore-sql-server-databases/